# Perl may be unconfigured?

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, perl, debconf

Hi I have error when I want to install,remove or configure my package this is the error

```
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate Debconf/Log.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debconf::Log module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0 /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/5.20.0 .) at (eval 1) line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 4.
) -- aborting
Setting up debconf (1.5.51ubuntu2) ...
Can't locate Debconf/Db.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debconf::Db module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0 /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/apps/perl/lib/5.20.0 .) at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

someone can tell me what should I do ?

Comment: Look for Q&A about running `dpgk`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by copying the contents of `/usr/share/perl5` & `/usr/share/perl` from another Ubuntu machine (Same version of the OS - in my case Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try :

```
apt-file search Debconf/Db.pm
debconf: /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm
```

so perhaps

```
apt-get install debconf
```

work fine for you

Comment: it's same result,  i think apt-get is broken so maybe can't fix by apt-get too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete perl folder from directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl` and run sudo apt-get install -f command. System will try to unpack perl packages from its already maintained package list and the issue will be resolved. I tried this on 18.04